# Removing some patterns before a particular string using Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove some patterns between two "/" from the string, for example:

**Input**

`/DT_Gateway/gateway/ACC/input/..`

**Output**

`/DT_Gateway/gateway/ACC`

I have tried writing this code, but getting an error. I am new to Java, please help.

```
public class cut {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myString = "/DT_Gateway/gateway/ACC/input/..";
        String newString = myString.substring(myString.lastIndexOf("/")+1, myString.indexOf("/.."));
        System.out.println(newString);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you give some more examples of inputs and expected outputs? The one you've given doesn't seem to illustrate removing something between two slashes, per your requirement.

Comment: If this is a file path, you could use `File` to clear the `.` and `..` folders for you...

Comment: What do you mean by "...getting error"? Please share any error messages you are getting, or explain what didn't work.

Comment: input:/DT_Gateway/gateway/ACC/input/../../.. output:/DT_Gateway/ input:/ABC/XYZ/.. output:/ABC/ @jsheeran

Comment: i am getting output as a string if i am changing number ass parameter @KevinAnderson

Comment: You are getting error because myString.lastIndexOf("/")+1 is out of range , if you delete +1 you will not get the error , but you will not get even the result you expect

Comment: i have tried using -5 taking this in the range after that i am getting 'input' as a output which is variable in many cases, is there any way to fix that

Answer (score 0):

Note : this is a very **custom** solution to your problem, not a general way to do it .

```
String myString = "/DT_Gateway/gateway/ACC/input/..";
            String newString = myString.substring(0, myString.indexOf("/i"));
            System.out.println(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution with regex:

```
"/DT_Gateway/gateway/ACC/input/..".replaceAll("(/[^/]+){2}$", "")
```

The regex is basically find two of the following pattern at the end of the string

```
/[^/]+
```

This means a forward slash followed by an unlimited number of non-forward-slashes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that relative paths should be normalized, XXX/.. removed.

That would go as follows

```
String myString = "/DT_Gateway/gateway/ACC/input/..";
System.out.println(myString.replaceAll("/[^/]+/\\.\\.(/|$)", "$1"));

String myString2 = "/DT_Gateway/gateway/ACC/input/../x.txt";
System.out.println(myString2.replaceAll("/[^/]+/\\.\\.(/|$)", "$1"));

Path path = Paths.get(myString);
System.out.println(path.normalize().toString());

Path path2 = Paths.get(myString2);
System.out.println(path2.normalize().toString());


/DT_Gateway/gateway/ACC
/DT_Gateway/gateway/ACC/x.txt
/DT_Gateway/gateway/ACC
/DT_Gateway/gateway/ACC/x.txt
```

Java Path is - for (all kinds of) file systems - quite the tool.

Especially as there is `XXX/../..`